# Drawing states separately with d3 js and country topojson file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have a topojson which contains state's paths. I want the user to be able to hover over a state and the state to appear in a different svg. So far, I've tried to extract the geometry out of the topojson (d.geometry , d.geometry.coordinates etc) But I'm not able to do it. 
Maybe I need to draw a polygon out of that, but some states are of type "Polygon" and some of them are of type "MultiPolgyon".

Any ideas/suggestions?

Edit : Here's my code

```
var svg = d3.select("#india-map")
.append("svg")
.attr("width",width).attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
.attr("height", height)

var stateSvg = d3.select("#state-map")
.append("svg")
.append("g")
.attr("height", height)
.attr("width", width);


var g = svg.append("g");

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center([86, 27])
  .scale(1200);

var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

var pc_geojson = topojson.feature(pc, pc.objects.india_pc_2014);
var st_geojson = topojson.feature(state_json, state_json.objects.india_state_2014);

g.selectAll(".pc")
    .data(pc_geojson.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "pc")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("id", function(d){ return d.properties.Constituency;})
    .attr("fill", "orange")
    .on("click", function(d){
        drawCons(d);
    });

function drawCons(d){
 stateSvg.selectAll(".pc2")
   .data(d)
   .enter().append("path")
   .attr("class","pc2")
   .attr("d", path)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `topojson.feature()` to extract a country?

Comment: Yes,I extract geojson by doing `var g = topojson.feature(country, country.objects.states)` (this works and I see the map) and then I tried doing this on hover, `var state = topojson.feature(g, d)` but it doesn't work

Comment: Ok in this case you don't need `topojson.feature` again. `g` should be a list of countries in GeoJSON format that you can extract the selected country from, e.g. by checking the name or something similarly suitable that is part of the data.

Comment: I get an object to type "feature" when I select that object. To draw this I'm doing `svg.selectAll("path").data(feature).enter().append("path")` yet I see no svg being drawn in the html.

Comment: What context does this code appear in? Are there `path`s in the SVG already?

Comment: I changed that to `svg.selectAll(".cs").data(feature).enter().append("path").attr("class","cs")` . Still can't see anything. This is wrapped inside the event listener for the bigger svg.

Comment: Could you post a complete example please?

Comment: Done, please have a look.

Comment: Is it possible that the `path` is added to the SVG, but you can't see it because it's outside the viewport?

Comment: Nope, I'm inspecting the svg through chrome and the svg:g is empty

Comment: Then either the `drawCons` code isn't run or there are elements with class "pc2" in there already.

Comment: I add `drawCons` inline and changed the class to something else, and still don't see anything. Maybe something else is the problem.

Comment: Ah, I think it's just a typo -- should be `.data([d])` instead of `.data(d)`. Quick and dirty example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/raw/10587926/).

Comment: Awesome, thanks Lars! Can you please post this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.data()` expects to be given an array of objects to be matched against the selection. You're passing a single object, so it doesn't work. You can either use `.datum(d)` or `.data([d])` to make it work.

Quick and dirty demo [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/raw/10587926/).

Comment: Where did you get the CA topojson for your demo?

Comment: Can't remember now, but feel free to use it for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks but I need different states. I'm going to try to use the TopoJSON US Atlas and see if there are individual makefiles for states and their counties.